# How do you beat someone who is bigger faster and stronger than you

Tags: training, technique, recommendation, style

Let me preface by saying this is a very open ended question What I'm looking for in the answer is the general approach the mental aspect of how you should fight someone like this. For example when the fight starts should you try to catch the person of guard and try to end it as quickly as possible, Should you try to lure your opponent into a false sense of security, endure and look for an opening to risk everything on? The second part is specific techniques like certain kicks or submissions or overall like martial arts styles Muay Thai or Jujutsu would be best. Another way I could to think of this is trying to figure out the best way for technique and combat intelligence to overcome physical superiority.

Assume that the physically advantaged person in question is also a mixed martial artist who has proficiency in a variety of martial arts technique. What are the best things to learn in order to best beat someone who beats you on all physical fronts?

Don't factor it difficulty of learning the techniques you recommend for the physically disadvantaged person. I want this to be about an optimal scenario where technique for the smaller person isn't an issue and more about how to use it instead of if they can learn it.

Comment: You do realise that having a weapon counts for more than size speed or strength or technique?  So The correct answer is to have a gun or a knife.  It sounds flippant but without a context for why this fight is even happening it's the correct answer.

Comment: I guess I should have specified more I have a close friend and rival who I have been doing martial arts with since I've been about 8 yeards old and I'm in my early twenties now We used to have the exact same height and build and were at least comparable in skill until we were both about 16 years old now he has about 30 lbs on me 3 inches on me and is also faster than me. We are still about as experienced and as skilled as each other but when we spar I feel the biggest challenge are his physical advantage more than his a higher skill in martial arts and I want to overcome that

Comment: How are you sparing? Are you meeting in competitions?

Comment: We haven't sparred officially for years right now we only practice in a gym while going about 75% at the most. Mainly because of the difference in weight classes I would like to match him officially however but only when I'm ready first. I know there won't be a shortcut or clear cut or a single answer I'm just looking for a direction to start in to get more confident enough to have an official match. I'm very competitive more so with him than with anyone else and I really do not want to lose and I am looking for every advantage I can get before hand.

Comment: I answered a similar question: https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/12721/how-to-beat-a-vastly-superior-opponent/12723#12723